# How to create Wind effect on circle logo

Tags: animation, physics, cloth-simulation, force-fields

I am trying to animate a logo in the shape of a circle. The idea was to have it floating in the air and have some wind going through it.

What I have done so far:

- I have used cloth simulation and the wind force field, which all works easily with a rectangular plane, but not so well with a circle.
- I have also tried to subdivide the circle by hand, I have set gravity to a negative value and also used a Vertex Group (one vertex on the left) as a Pin Group but this all yields more comical results.

What I need help with:

- How do I create the proper plane for the circular logo? It doesn't seem to work as well as the rectangular shape with subdivisions. I have already tried to cut out a circle from a subdivided plane with a boolean function but that has failed.
- How can I achieve the circular shape to stay in place without pinning it to a spot or having it float away in negative gravity?

**Images**
Unfortunately I can't find a perfect example so you'll have to bear with the screenshots of my recent tries:

This the force field and the circle shape (pinned with one vertex on the left and negative gravity)
[image: Scene Setup]

This is just an example of what it should look like on the front.
[image: Front View]

Edit:
I have tried knife project on the plane like suggested in the comments. Have to remove the outer edges afterwards.

[image: Knife Project Circle on Subdivided Plane]

Edit 2:
It seems to work now, although I am still having trouble to get the edges really smooth and the plane itself to be absolutely smooth in the renderer. Still, thanks a lot for your input so far!

[image]

Comment: if your current topology (concentrical circles) doesn't work you could create a circle and cut a perpendicular grid with the Knife Project tool

Comment: thanks; i will try that!

Comment: is it supposed to move like a flag? You can rotate the force field object on the Z axis so that it changes the wind direction and give better result; also vary its strength

Comment: yes, it should stay in place and wave a little like a flag. the problem is that i have to select a "pin" which makes the movement look weird. It should simple float in the air and have a little flag-like movement throug the force field.

Comment: I have tried the knife project idea, (see edited post) but it didnt work regarding the edges. 

EDIT: MY BAD, Have to remove the outer shapes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as I said you can cut a grid with the *Knife Project* tool. Then to make it work properly, first create the pin group:

[image]

Choose *Cloth > Cotton* for example. Create a *Force Field > Wind* and a *Force Field > Turbulence*. Make the Wind rotate and vary its *Strength* value through time. Maybe also create a simple edge and give the circle object a *Copy Scale* constraint with the edge as *Target*, and change the height of the edge a bit so that the circle vary its height a bit as well, it will create more folds:

[image]

Comment: That actually helps a lot to understand your input better, thank you! I'll try to follow your steps.

Comment: Are you using a subdivision modifier to get the circle surface smooth?

Comment: Yes Subdivision Surface modifier + Shade Smooth

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick and perfect help :)

Comment: I have a follow-up question: I was successful in creating the circle shape as well as the wind/turbulence setup like you described and showed in your post. However, I did not quite understand what you meant with "create a simple edge" while trying to implement your Copy Scale technique. Could you explain it a bit more? Thanks in advance if you have the time :)

Comment: in the gif you can see that on the right of the wind object I've created a vertical edge, I give the flag a Copy Scale with this edge as Target, I animate/scale the edge so that flag squeaze a bit on the Z axis and fold a bit, here is the file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=DRbzJvSg" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/DRbzJvSg/)

Comment: wow, thank you. now that I see the object, I finally understand that the "edge" is just the edge of a plane. sorry i didnt get the before. makes perfect sense now!